# P.d.f. of $Y={1\over \sigma^2}X_1X_2$. where $(X_1,X_2)$ is a random vector with bivariate normal distribution.

Tags: probability

$(X_1,X_2)$ is a random vector with bivariate normal distribution.
We have $E(X_k)=0$ and $E(X_jX_k)= \sigma^2 >0$ for $k,j=1,2$.
Try to find the probability density function for random variable $Y={1\over \sigma^2}X_1X_2$.

I know how to determine the p.d.f when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. But how do I proceed in this setting?

Comment: It might be worth considering the correlation of $X_1$ and $X_2$ as a clue as to what is going on

Comment: @Henry Could you elaborate? I'm still new to this.

Comment: Do I understand the conditions properly? $E(X_1^2) = E(X_1X_2)=E(X_2^2)=\sigma^2$?

Comment: @NCh Yes I think it's the case.

Comment: Then find the correlation coefficient and conclude.